# Is it possible to insert the full reference of an article in the middle of a Rmarkdown document using citation keys?

Tags: r-markdown, bibliography, citations

[Here](http://rmarkdown.rstudio.com/authoring_bibliographies_and_citations.html) I learn how to insert citations in the middle of a text and generate a full bibliography at the end of the document. I wonder whether it is possible to have an output like this using citation keys:

Bla bla bla.

Watson, J. D., & Crick, F. H. (1953). Molecular structure of nucleic acids. Nature, 171(4356), 737-738.

Bla bla bla.

Answer (score 1):

### In-text full references/citations in RMarkdown using `Bibtex`-package.

Solution using [bibtex-package](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46384808) proposed by [Samuel-Rosa](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3365410/samuel-rosa).
An example with citations for packages:

0. Example `.bib` file

```
knitr::write_bib("R"), "example.bib")
```

1. Read your `.bib` file into R.

```
refs <- bibtex::read.bib("example.bib")
```

2. Using [in-line chunks](https://bookdown.org/yihui/rmarkdown/r-code.html), select the entry of interest, e.g. `R-base`, print the entry, and "capture" it as character for RMarkdown output.

```
Example full reference for R:  
> `r capture.output(print(refs["R-base"]))`
```

#### Output:

Example full reference for R:

> R Core Team (2021). *R: A Language and Environment for Statistical Computing*. R Foundation for Statistical Computing, Vienna, Austria. <URL: [https://www.R-project.org/>](https://www.R-project.org/%3E).