# Full citation in RMarkdown?

Tags: r-markdown

Is there any way to insert a fully formatted citation in RMarkdown in-text. For example, something like this: You enter the citation key

@watson1953

and it renders (as a latex PDF) as

Watson, J. D., & Crick, F. H. C. (1953). Molecular structure of nucleic acids: A structure for deoxyribose nucleic acid. Nature, 171(737-738), 3-12.

But it does it in exact location of the citation key. The bibliography at the end of the document should also be suppressed.

Is there any way to do this? I couldn't find anything either here or through searching google.

Comment: Rmarkdown uses csl (citation style language). Just find a style that suits your need; here is the main repo : https://www.zotero.org/styles

Comment: After downloading the csl and placing it in your root folder, add the following to your yaml: csl: yourcsl.csl

Comment: scoa and Nick: your comments are not in any way related to the question asked.

Comment: Have a look at this solution using the `bibtex` package: https://stackoverflow.com/a/68874049/6757392

Answer (score 1):

Use [visual markdown editing mode](https://rstudio.github.io/visual-markdown-editing/#/citations) in RStudio 1.4.

> Once you’ve inserted a citation, place the cursor over it to see a preview of it along with a link to the source if one is available:
>
> [image: citation]

Answer (score 0):

I assume you're using RStudio, which uses Pandoc to render R Markdown documents. You need to put the citation tag inside brackets, like `[@watson1953]`. If you put a citation without `[ ]`, it will render an in-line citation.

According to the [Pandoc User's Guide - Citations](https://pandoc.org/MANUAL.html#citations):

> Citations go inside square brackets and are separated by semicolons. Each citation must have a key, composed of ‘@’ + the citation identifier from the database, and may optionally have a prefix, a locator, and a suffix. [...]
>
> [...]
>
> You can also write an ***in-text citation***, as follows:
>
> ```
> @smith04 says blah.
>
> @smith04 [p. 33] says blah.
> ```

, emphasis mine.

Answer (score 0):

You can follow Andrew Heiss's solution, which involves using an APA curriculum vitae `csl` file, which will print the full reference in-line instead of in a references list at the end of your document.

You can find the csl file at the [Zotero CSL repository](https://www.zotero.org/styles?q=id%3Aapa-cv). Full details on how to use other citation styles in Andrew Heiss original [post](https://www.andrewheiss.com/blog/2023/01/09/syllabus-csl-pandoc/).