# Include the text of a `bibentry` in the (R)markdown text body output

Tags: r, knitr, r-markdown, bibtex

I have been looking for a solution to include the full text of a reference item (`bibentry`) in the body of the (R)markdown text document, that is, before the reference list. This can be done with LaTeX (https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/49048/how-to-cite-one-bibentry-in-full-length-in-the-body-text). Can it be done with (R)markdown?

Comment: `rmarkdown` uses pandoc to render output formats. If your output is LaTeX then you can include those commands directly. However those commands will cause other output formats to fail compiling.

Comment: This is related to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42602055/full-citation-in-rmarkdown

Comment: @kevin.arseneau, then there is no solution for HLML and DOCX outputs?

Comment: @Samuel-Rose, not that I am aware. Although, I would say that the `bookdown` package has enhanced cross-referencing and may provide an html solution. Check out the `html_document2` output format.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A reasonable solution is to read and parse the bibliography database using, for example, the R-package **bibtex** and then `capture.output` of `print` as a character string, which can then be used to include the full text of a reference item (bibentry) in the body of the (R)markdown text document.

For example:

````
```{r, echo=FALSE}
biblio <- bibtex::read.bib("my-biblio-database.bib")
```
````

Then, in line, use:

```
`r capture.output(print(biblio["my-bibkey"]))`
```

which will print the reference text.

Comment: this would be useful if it was possible to specify a csl file for formatting; unfortunately it doesn't seem possible

Answer (score 2):

The [`bibtex`](https://cran.r-project.org/package=bibtex) interprets the bibliography file and places it into the [`bibentry`](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-patched/library/utils/html/bibentry.html) class, which is part of the [`utils`](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-patched/library/utils/html/utils-package.html) package.

Thus, the correct way of showing a citation is to switch away from the accepted answer of:

```
`r capture.output(biblio["my-bibkey"])`
```

to

```
`r format(biblio["my-bibkey"], style = "text")`
```

Note, we're using the [`utils:::format.bibentry(entry, style = "text")`](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-patched/library/utils/html/bibentry.html) to correctly set the output display.