# Including entire bibliographic entry in RMarkdown - equivalent of \fullcite?

Tags: latex, r-markdown, knitr, biblatex

Is there a way to include an entire bibliographic entry in the main text of my Rmarkdown document?  If I were using LaTeX, I'd use `\fullcite{Smith2000}`.  And then it would print, wherever I wanted:

Smith, J. 2000.  *A nice book*. Oxford: Oxford University Press.

Here's a sample .Rmd file

````
---
title: "hi"
author: "dmt"
date: "30/04/2020"
output: html_document
bibliography: bib.bib
biblio-style: apalike
---

```{r setup, include=FALSE}
knitr::opts_chunk$set(echo = TRUE)
```

## R Markdown


```{r cars}
summary(cars)
```

Here is the citation of a book I am reading:

@Smith2000

But I would like to put the whole reference here like this: 

Smith, J. 2000. A nice book. Oxford: Oxford University Press.

How can I do this without writing it out?
````

And here's a sample .bib file:

```
@book{Smith2000,
    Address = {Oxford},
    Author = {Smith, J},
    Date-Added = {2020-04-30 17:03:32 +0100},
    Date-Modified = {2020-04-30 17:04:03 +0100},
    Publisher = {Oxford University Press},
    Title = {A nice book},
    Year = {2000}}
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Include the text of a \`bibentry\` in the (R)markdown text body output](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46260431/include-the-text-of-a-bibentry-in-the-rmarkdown-text-body-output)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This works fine for me:

Execute this chunk in your RMD file:

````
```{r, echo=FALSE}
biblio <- bibtex::read.bib("bib.bib")
```
````

Then you can use the following line in your script:

```
`r capture.output(print(biblio["Smith2000"]))`
```