# How to use a bibtex citation key in a quarto gt table?

Tags: r, gt, quarto

I would like to add a bibtex reference to the notes for a `gt` table in Quarto, but using `@citationkey` does not seem to work. Does anyone know how to do it?

Here's a reproducible example:

````
---
title: "Untitled"
format: pdf
bibliography: refs.bib
---

```{r}
#| include: false
library(dplyr)
library(gt)

    ```

Here I can cite @dirac

But below I get only the literal "@dirac". If I do not include the quotation marks, the code does not compile.

```{r}
#| include: true
#| echo: false

head(mtcars) %>%
  gt() %>%
  tab_source_note("@dirac")
    ```

# References {-}
````

And the reference in `refs.bib`:

```
@book{dirac,
  title={The Principles of Quantum Mechanics},
  author={Paul Adrien Maurice Dirac},
  isbn={9780198520115},
  series={International series of monographs on physics},
  year={1981},
  publisher={Clarendon Press},
  keywords = {physics}
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Following [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46260431/include-the-text-of-a-bibentry-in-the-rmarkdown-text-body-output/46384808#46384808) you could read your bib file via `bibtex::read.bib`. Afterwards you could add your citation to the `gt` table via `cite` like so:

````
---
title: "Untitled"
format: pdf
bibliography: refs.bib
---

```{r}
#| include: false
library(dplyr)
library(gt)
library(bibtex)
```
```{r}
biblio <- bibtex::read.bib("refs.bib")
```

Here I can cite @dirac

But below I get only the literal "@dirac". If I do not include the quotation marks, the code does not compile.

```{r}
#| include: true
#| echo: false
head(mtcars) %>%
  gt() %>%
  tab_source_note(cite("dirac", biblio, textual = TRUE))
```
````

[image]

Comment: and for `kableExtra` package?